# Programatically expand the submenu of a ShareActionProvider MenuItem

Tags: android

I'm using the standard Android ShareActionProvider to display a menu of possible sharing services in an Action Bar.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Is there any way to programatically open the submenu of sharing services when the activity is created?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I'm having the same question.

Answer (score 1):

```java
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
      menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.action_share, 0);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```